# Crystal Reports multiple pages with parameter

Tags: crystal-reports

First, sorry for my English, i'll try do the best!

I have a report of tags when a data (Number01) with number of tags to print (amount of packages).
The problem is generate in crystal reports many pages as the Number01 indicates.
In this case is **only one** record with a field that indicates the amount of tags to print (Number01).

I not execute the report programatically and don't have access to the database, I only can work with the report in crystal reports because the program that runs the report is privative and, in this case, the program send **only one** record.

Any way for do it? or any idea to solve printing (creating) multiple pages?

I hope I explained well.
Many Thanks!

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you're wanting a counter of some sort? You can use a RUNNING TOTAL to count each record and print that number in your page label. I think that's what you're wanting.

Comment: First, thanks for the reply. I not want a counter, I want to print many pages as the Number01 indicates. I receive a record with a number in cell "Number01", i want to print amount of tags as the Number01 indicates. i.e. I receive "3" in Number01, I want to print three tags, I mean three page.